# Can A-frame 'look-at' component look at the default camera?

Tags: aframe

Is it possible to get the a-frame [`look-at` component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-look-at-component) to look at the default camera? Since it does not have an ID or a class by default I don't know how to target it.

I have tried adding `[camera]` as the selector value [as per the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-look-at-component#usage) like so;

```
    <a-text 
      value="Look at test"
      look-at="[camera]">
    </a-text>
```

but it does not seem to work for me. I feel I am missing something obvious here.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is correct, but at the time the `look-at` component is initialized, the camera is not yet on the scene.

Try creating a component, which will wait until the scene is loaded,

```
this.el.sceneEl.addEventListener("loaded", (e)=>{....
```

or at least for `window.onload`.

Check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1na67dqr/).

Comment: Thank you Piotr, that does work. It seems a shame you cannot use the component in that way without writing a script. Thanks for the explanation. If anyone is looking for a way to do this without writing a script, this similar component will do it https://github.com/blairmacintyre/aframe-look-at-billboard-component

Comment: Should this example still be working? I tried moving with WASD on my monitor in your glitch-example, but the cube is not looking at me

Comment: @Ava yea something was off, I've updated the answer to the newest `a-frame` version.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a-text value="Look at test" look-at="#cam"></a-text>
<a-camera id="cam"></a-camera>
```

this should work.....

Comment: Hi Karan, thanks for your answer but that does not work, the default camera does not have an ID. I have just found another very similar component that can look at the default camera https://github.com/blairmacintyre/aframe-look-at-billboard-component. I'm not going to post that as an answer just in case there is a way to do it with the original mentioned in the question.